# From Dictionary to Array and back

Tags: swift, dictionary, uicollectionview

I use a Dictionary to store info from which a collectionview is populated and the info in the dictionary is paired with data from a urlsession.

My Dictionary looks like this:

```
var allDict = ["Section1": ["device1", "device2"], "Section2": ["device3", "device4"]]
```

I then use a struct to get an array which feeds my collectionview cells and sections:

```
struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
}
var objectArray = [Objects]()

for (key, value) in allDict {
    objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
}
```

The outcome is this:

```
ObjectArray:  [__lldb_expr_134.Objects(sectionName: Section1, sectionObjects: ["device1", "device2"]), __lldb_expr_134.Objects(sectionName: Section2, sectionObjects: ["device3", "device4"])]
["device1", "device2"]
```

Now, the Problem is that I want to be able to rearrange the cells and I am able to rearrange the data in the array, but I have to get it back to the dictionary.
I'm aware that a dictionary is unsorted, but while testing I never hat the problem that the devices changed there place in the array inside the dictionary.

My idea is to rearrange the ObjectArray and then clear the dictionary and put the data back in.
So I tried to get the data from ObjectArray back using a for loop but I don't get it right, here is what I tried:

I found out I can access the data like this:

```
print(objectArray[0].sectionObjects)
["device1", "device2"]
```

So I tried:

```
for items in objectArray {
    print(items)   
    for (name) in items.sectionObjects {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

there I get this:

```
device1
device2
```

But when I do:

```
for items in objectArray {
    print(items)
    
    for (name) in items.sectionName {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

I get this:

```
S
e
c
t
i
o
n
1
```

All I want is something like:

```
for (sectionNAme, sectionObjects) in objectArray {
    newDictionary[sectionName] += [sectionObjects]
}
```

but this gets me this:  Expression type '[Objects]' is ambiguous without more context

Sorry, for the long text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the loop in this way

```
for object in objectArray {
    newDictionary[object.sectionName] = object.sectionObjects
}
```

`object` represents one `Objects` instance – by the way it's recommended to name the struct in singular form `Object` – you get the name with `object.sectionName` and the objects with `object.sectionObjects`

---

Notes:

```
S
e
c
t
i
o
n
1
```

occurs because you treat the name string as array and you are iterating through the **characters** of the string.

---

Since you are using the implicit memberwise initializer anyway I would declare the struct with non-optional members as `Section` and shorten the member names:

```
struct Section {
    var name : String
    var objects : [String]
}
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you very mucht, works like a charm. and thank you for your great explanation!!